# How do I save the publish location in SVN for VisualStudio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn

Where is the publish location stored in a VisualStudio project? How can I make sure when a different developer checks out my project that they can publish the project to the same location. This is for internal projects.

Update: This is for web projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in de project file as a property:

```
<PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl> 

<InstallUrl>\\fileserver\Public\MyApp\</InstallUrl>
```

Assuming your project file is also in svn it should already work...

Comment: Do you mean `/project.Publish.xml`?

Comment: @Mike Wills Not sure but my example is from VS2010 and I see know that you are on 2008, I unloaded the project file (in my case WinApp.csproj) for and opened it in the xml editor to look it up.